# How does $\int \tan x dx$ equal to $ \log( \sec x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How can the integration result in $\sec x$? What operations are done here?

Comment: substitute $u = \cos{x}$

Comment: Try writing $tan(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let $u=\cos x$ then $du=-\sin x \,dx$ so that we get
$$\int \tan x dx=\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}dx=\int-\frac{1}{u}du=-\ln|u|+C=-\ln|\cos x|+C$$

$$=\ln|(\cos x)^{-1}|+C=\ln|\sec x|+C$$

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is -

$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx = \log|f(x)| + c$

$\int tan(x) dx = \int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}dx$

As derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$, so we can write it as,

$=-\int\frac{-\sin x}{\cos x}dx$

$=-\log |\cos x|+C$

$=\log |(\cos x)^{-1}|+C$

$=\log |\sec x|+C$

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that if $\frac{d}{dx} F(x) = f(x),$ then
$\int f(x)\,dx = F(x) + C,$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Therefore all you need to do to verify that the given formula for the integral $\int\tan(x)\,dx$ is correct (for $-\frac\pi2 < x < \frac\pi2$)
is to evaluate
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \log(\sec(x)).
$$

Is that derivative equal to $\tan(x)$? If so, then 
$\int\tan(x)\,dx = \log(\sec(x)) + C$ for $-\frac\pi2 < x < \frac\pi2.$

In principle, if an integral can be solved by setting it equal to some function you can write, then all you need to do to solve the integral
is to guess the solution and then check it via differentiation.

All the other techniques for "solving" the integrals are just methods
for guessing the solution. Note that some of them are extremely *good*
methods for guessing the solution that work for many problems that look like this one.
That is, those techniques are the answer to the question, "How can I solve this integral" when someone hasn't already told you the solution.

Most of the techniques for solving integrals work on the same principle,
$\frac{d}{dx} F(x) = f(x)$ then
$\int f(x)\,dx = F(x) + C,$
so you can solve $\int f(x)\,dx$ if you remember having seen the fact
that $\frac{d}{dx} F(x) = f(x).$
The trick is, if you get an integral that doesn't look like one whose solution you already know, 
transform it into an integral whose solution you *do* already know.

Answer (score 0):

Because $d(\sec x)=\sec x\tan x\,dx$ and $\frac{\sec x}{\sec x}=1$ you can see the integral as 
$$\begin{align}
\int\tan x \frac{\sec x}{\sec x}\,dx\;&=\;\int\frac{d(\sec x)}{\sec x}\\
&=\;\ln|\sec x|+C\,.\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Nothing too complicated. It's just an integral substitution: $$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \, dx =- \int \frac{d( \cos(x))}{\cos(x)} = -\log\, \cos(x)+C = \log\, \sec(x)+C$$

Comment: [Be nice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Is the notation that @4445283 uses common for u-substitution?

Comment: @JohnLou Not everyone uses it, but yes, it is common enough. A slightly more "traditional" way of writing $d(\cos(x))$ is $(\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x))dx.$

Comment: @JohnLou It's called a Riemann-Stieltjes integral